# Dialog menu - Space between menuitems

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, dialog

I want to add a some space between the menuitems of a `dialog menu`.

Is there any way to do it?

I created a menu, with "empty Buttons" which call the menu again. This looks like what i want.

But the Problem is, that i need to push now the arrow-down button two times to reach the next button, becaus it redirects also to the empty Buttons.

Is it possible to deactivate some menuitems but leave them there as placeholder?

My code looks like this:

```
main_menu() {
dialog --clear
LANG=de_DE
dialog --no-cancel --ok-label "Auswahl" --default-item '1' --backtitle "" --title "TestMenu"\
    --menu "\n Test                                        Test" 25 80 24\
        '' ""\
        1 " Menupunkt1"\
        '' ""\
        2 " Menupunkt2"\
        '' ""\
        3 " Menupunkt3"\
        '' ""\
        4 " Menupunkt4"\
        '' ""\
        5 " Menupunkt5"\
        '' ""\
        0 " Abmelden" 2>$_temp

opt=${?}
if [ $opt != 0 ]; then rm $_temp; exit; fi
menuitem=`cat $_temp`
echo "menu=$menuitem"
case $menuitem in
1) ${Funktion_Button1}
        main_menu;;
2) ${Funktion_Button2}
        main_menu;;
3) ${Funktion_Button3}
        main_menu;;
4) ${Funktion_Button4}
        main_menu;;
5) ${Funktion_Button5}
        main_menu;;
0) rm $_temp; rm -f /tmp/menu.*; rm -f /tmp/answer.*; exit;;
esac
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add those buttons in the way you have added and all point to main menu, which you may change later.

If Possible, instead of using arrow keys to move, use Options numbers to navigate, and it would be easy to skip invalid/deactivated options like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Access Choices by numbers

PS3='Please enter your choice: '
options=("Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
case $opt in
    "Option 1")
        echo "you chose choice 1"
        ;;
    "Option 2")
        echo "you chose choice 2"
        ;;
    "Option 3")
        echo "you chose choice $REPLY which is $opt"
        ;;
    "Quit")
        break
        ;;
    *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
esac
done
```

Comment: I need to use the arrow keys. Your code work like my code but do not solve the problem.